# does setStorageEncryption encrypt all mobile storage memory?

Tags: android, security, encryption, storage

I've been requested to apply  the "setStorageEncryption" in an Android App as a security policy.

Once this policy is applied, does it affect all storage memory in the device?
Can it be used to only encrypt selected files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once this policy is applied, does it affect all storage memory in the device?

Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setStorageEncryption%28android.content.ComponentName,%20boolean%29):

> This policy controls encryption of the secure (application data) storage area. Data written to other storage areas may or may not be encrypted, and this policy does not require or control the encryption of any other storage areas. There is one exception: If isExternalStorageEmulated() is true, then the directory returned by getExternalStorageDirectory() must be written to disk within the encrypted storage area.

Most devices have emulated external storage, by which I mean that the external storage is part of the same partition as internal storage, and `isExternalStorageEmulated()` would return `true`.

> Can it be used to only encrypt selected files?

No, sorry.

Comment: I already read the documentation however I still had some doubts that I wanted to confirm. Thanks.